# erro while cross compile opencv program for arm

Tags: linux, opencv

arm-linux-g++ -o samplecam usbcam.c `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
usbcam.c:25: note: the mangling of 'va_list' has changed in GCC 4.4
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [usbcam] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

What is the question? What do you do? I assume that your pkg-config gets the settings for the library installed in your build machine (path /usr/local/lib suggests that). No wonder that it won't link with ARM binaries.

If you have ARM build of opencv, along with it's SDK, you should set PKG_CONFIG_PATH to your /opt/crosstoolchain/.../opencv/lib/pkgconfig before configuring the build?

Comment: I am new to linux i am not understood what you are telling can you please explain me in detail how can i cross compile for ARM

Comment: Ok, here I go. 1. Ensure that you're using the cross compiler, and not the default compiler of your distro. 2. Ensure that you're linking and compiling with/against ARM libraries, and not your host libraries. Problems like you pasted, "could not read symbols: File in wrong format" suggest, that you try to link build for one architecture with object files/libs for other architecture. To solve action point 1., you need to put your ARM compiler in PATH, and provide --host=(cross architecture), to solve AP 2., use PKG_CONFIG_PATH. Google for it, character limit is too short to describe it here.